# best way to filter out <img> tags when webscraping?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Im using beautifulsoup to do some webscraping and want to know the best way to filter out the img tags from any table entries i scrape so the result of filtering the td.text attribute in this code fragment would return only usefultext

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    usefultext
    <img src='imgsrc' alt='*'>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you seen the `extract()` function? Here's the [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: when you do `td.text` you get back `usefultext`, no need to extract the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the soup, `useful_text` and once the soup has been created, as documentation will [explain](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you can go up and down the tree by selecting `tags`, in this case I selected the `td` tag and if it has multiple strings I will use the `get_text()` function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

html = '''<tr>
  <td>
    usefultext
    <img src='imgsrc' alt='*'>
  </td>
</tr>'''

useful_text = BeautifulSoup(html)
useful_text.td.get_text()
```

```
[out]:

'\n    usefultext\n    \n'
```

If you have multiple `td` tags then you will want to use the `next_siblings` function.

I highly recommend reading the documentation and playing around.